# Formatting percent number to zh (simplified Chinese) using the right percent sign (ie. ％)

Tags: swift, percentage, chinese-locale, numberformatter

I'd like to use `NumberFormatter` to generate zh-localised percents as follows, in order to supersede my own code as follow:

```
    let locale = Locale(identifier: lang)

    let formatter = NumberFormatter()
    formatter.locale = locale
    formatter.numberStyle = .percent
    formatter.maximumFractionDigits = d

    let number = NSNumber(value: Double(n))

    if let r = formatter.string(from: number) {
        if lang == "zh" { return r.replace(["%"], withString: "％")

        return r
    }
    // My fallback code
```

Unfortunately, unlike my code, in simplified Chinese `NumberFormatter` generates latin `%` sign rather than the chinese version `％` (hence the replacement patch I do).

I am wondering if one could tweak `NumberFormatter` further so that it take care of it? (and in other non-latin languages).

Answer (score 3):

You seem to imply that what `NumberFormatter` outputs is incorrect. However, as a native Chinese, I can confidently say that "50%" is the natural way of writing a percentage in the `zh` locale. This is also evident from this Baidu Baike (Chinese counterpart of Wikipedia) [article](https://baike.baidu.com/item/%E4%BA%BA%E5%8F%A3%E5%A2%9E%E9%95%BF%E7%8E%87). I have never seen any app write percentages with the full-width percentage sign. I can't even type it with the Chinese IME on my Mac.

To my eyes, "50％" looks weird, probably because it's mixing full-width and half-width characters. I've occasionally seen "５０％" in Japanese sites, but it's still rather rare.

if you *really* want, you can set the [`percentSymbol`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/numberformatter/1407789-percentsymbol) property in `NumberFormatter`:

```
let formatter = NumberFormatter()
formatter.percentSymbol = "％"
formatter.numberStyle = .percent
print(formatter.string(from: 0.5) ?? "failed")
```

To be honest, I would trust the output of `NumberFormatter`, which is designed by a bunch of professional localisation engineers.

Comment: Alas, this does not handle localisation then.

Comment: @StéphanedeLuca What gave you the idea that Chinese use full-width percent signs? The Japanese seems to use them more in my experience... But anyway, see the edit.

Comment: @StéphanedeLuca In a sense, setting `locale` already _handles_  localisation. `%` _is_ the correct symbol to use in the `zh` locale. What you are saying (that full-width percentage signs should be used in `zh` locale) is your _own_, non-standard kind of localisation that you defined yourself. It is only natural that you have to implement yourself. My suggestion is, just trust what `NumberFormatter` outputs.